# Is a multivalued function analytic over its branch cut?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, analyticity, branch-cuts

I want to evaluate the integral $\int_Cf(z)dz$, where C is the unit circle centered at the origin, and $f(z)$ = log(z+2).

I know that the integral of a function over a simple, closed contour is $0$ when the function is analytic on and inside of the contour. $log(z+2)$ is analytic in the region C, so would this integral evaluate to $0$? Or does that theorem not apply when the contour/region contains a branch cut?

Thank you!

Comment: Why does $C$ contain a branch cut? $Re(z+2) \geq 1$ on $C$ so you can definitely use the principal branch of the logarithm and get 0 for the integral by Cauchy

Comment: The Cauchy integral theorem says that $\int_C f(z)dz=0$ if $C$ is a (piecewise differentiable) closed curve and $f$ is analytic on a simply connected open set containing $C$. With $f(z) = \log(z+2)$ that $f$ is analytic on $|z| <1+\epsilon$ depends on which branch you are considering.